# Could not create a merge face

Tags: modeling, vertices

As shown in the picture, I've selected five vertices and pressed the <kbd>F</kbd> key. But every time I do this, Blender always said "Could not create a merge face."

[image]

Comment: Maybe that edge in the middle of your vertices is causing that issue...

Comment: You must create faces **separately**.

Comment: This should work... but 5 vertices? There are apparently only 4 bounding the visible triangles.. remove doubles?

Comment: Another way to merge two triangles into a quad is with Alt-J. Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You have two faces already.

You cannot create a face from that faces using  <kbd>F</kbd> .

I tried to dissolve the edge but no luck.

My solution:

Subdivide that edge and delete the vertex.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try going to edge select and select the edges then press <kbd>F</kbd>